# Is a cypher query, using a 'with' clause, executed in only one transaction?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, with-statement

In the [cypher manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html), it is explained the 'with' clause can be used to chain queries together where the output of one part can be given as the input to the next part. Does that mean that a query using the 'with' clause is executed in several transactions (one for each part in the chain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not use several transactions. A single query will be executed in one large transaction regardless of the number of `WITH` clauses it uses. The whole thing will either pass or fail as one unit.

Comment: You're right. I just tried a query using a `WITH` clause where the first part updates the database and the second reads the changes. If the second part is malformed, then the first will not be applied.

Thanks :)